# Binding error - Socket programming

Tags: c, windows, sockets

I have a problem binding the socket. There is no error as such, not sure why if fails on if condition.

```
int result = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsadata);
if(result != NO_ERROR)
{
    printf("\nThere is a problem at WSAStartup");
}
else
{
    printf("\nWSAStartup was ok");
}
list_sock = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
if(list_sock == -1)
{
    printf("\n Socket not created %d\n", list_sock);
}
else
{
    printf("\nSocket was created Succesfully");
}
HOSTENT *thishost;
char *ip;
u_short port;
port = 55555;
thishost = gethostbyname("localhost");
printf("\n");
printf("\nHost name is:%s ",thishost->h_name);
ip = inet_ntoa(*(struct in_addr*)*thishost->h_addr_list);
printf("\nip address is %s\n ", ip);
printf("Address type is:%i",thishost->h_addrtype);
service.sin_family = AF_INET;
service.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip);
service.sin_port = htons(port);
if(bind(list_sock,(SOCKADDR *)&service,sizeof(service))== SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    printf("Error during bind %s", strerror(errno));
}
else
{
    printf("All done");
}
WSACleanup();

return 0;
```

I get error at line

```
if(bind(list_sock,(SOCKADDR *)&service,sizeof(service))== SOCKET_ERROR)
```

But `strerror(errno))` gives me: "No error". But it still fails on if condition and does not bind.

Any help?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737550(v=vs.85).aspx : "If no error occurs, bind returns zero. Otherwise, it returns SOCKET_ERROR, and **a specific error code can be retrieved by calling WSAGetLastError**."

Comment: ok, I got it. It fails with 10014...  and I am on 64 bit system..will it make a difference?

Comment: Well, did you look up what that error means? What investigation did you do then?

Comment: Well! I looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/861154/winsock-error-code-10014. I guess, i has something to do with 64bit and 32bit,we it looked more probable for me..you suggest anything?

Comment: Your error has nothing to do with 32bit vs 64bit at all.  It has to do with a logic bug in your code.  See my answer for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

10014 is `WSAEFAULT`, which `bind()` returns when:

> The system detected an invalid pointer address in attempting to use a pointer argument in a call.
>
> This error is returned if the name parameter is NULL, the name or namelen parameter is not a valid part of the user address space, the namelen parameter is too small, the name parameter contains an incorrect address format for the associated address family, or **the first two bytes of the memory block specified by name do not match the address family associated with the socket descriptor s**.

You are creating an IPv6 socket (AF_INET6), but you are trying to bind it to an IPv4 (AF_INET) address.  That will not work.  You need to either create an IPv4 socket, or bind to an IPv6 address, depending on what you are trying to accomplish.

Lastly, don't use `gethostbyname("localhost")`.  First, it only supports IPv4.  Second, if you want to bind to the loopback IP, explicitly bind to `127.0.0.1` (IPv4) or `::1` (IPv6), which you can hard-code or at least use the `INETADDR_SETLOOPBACK()` macro in mstcpip.h.  If you want to bind to all available IPs, bind to `INADDR_ANY` (IPv4) or `IN6ADDR_ANY` (IPv6), which you can hard-code or at least use the `INETADDR_SETANY()` macro in mstcpip.h.  If you really want to use a function call, use `getaddrinfo()` instead, which supports both IPv4 and IPv6.